# Padding xAxis label in Mpchart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

All i want is padding the xAxis label like i have marked in below picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **yAxis.setXOffset(...)** can help you with that. You will probably have to play around a bit with the numbers to get the right distance.

Concerning the label count, you can use yAxis.setLabelCount(3, true) to set it to a fixed size of "3" for example.